# Consumer surplus in Logit model should minus actural payment?

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics, mathematical-economics, choice-theory

In Logit model, as Train(2003) said in his [book(page 55)](https://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2.html) said,

> "By
> definition, a person’s consumer surplus is the utility, in dollar terms,
> that the person receives in the choice situation. The decision-maker
> chooses the alternative that provides the greatest utility"

As to say, the consumer surplus equals to willingness-to-pay in Logit model. However, according defination, consumer surplus equals to willingness-to-pay minus actural payment, so I wonder why don't minus actural payment while calculating consumer surplus in Logit model.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not link to the article and there are multiple 2003 articles that have Train as a coauthor, is difficult to say what the context is there.

The definition can still be consistent. For example, people experience disutility when they loose money. Hence, the authors might be simply saying the consumer surplus is the dollar term net utility gain from transaction which would be equivalent to willingness-to-pay minus actual payment.